# Issue with Redis install "cc: Command not found"

Tags: gcc, redis

Installing redis is really easy. I have done it on several VM. But on one instance, I am facing the following problem.

```
[root@server redis-2.4.2]# make
cd src && make all
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/user/redis-2.4.2/src'
MAKE hiredis
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/user/redis-2.4.2/deps/hiredis'
cc -c -std=c99 -pedantic -O3 -fPIC -Wall -W -Wstrict-prototypes -Wwrite-strings    -g -ggdb  net.c
make[2]: cc: Command not found
make[2]: *** [net.o] Error 127
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/user/redis-2.4.2/deps/hiredis'
make[1]: *** [dependencies] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/user/redis-2.4.2/src'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Is there any other way to install redis?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

```
make[2]: cc: Command not found
```

This means that c compiler is uninstalled, or that it's not in `$PATH`.

Try `which cc`, this should tell the directory where `cc` is installed, if it is.

Otherwise, you can use your distro repository to install it.

In Ubuntu: `sudo aptitude install build-essential`.

Comment: I am using centos. # No package build-essential available. # how to I install cc ?

Comment: Try `yum install gcc` first, then try again make for redis.

Answer (score 90):

wget http://download.redis.io/redis-stable.tar.gz

tar xvzf redis-stable.tar.gz

cd redis-stable

sudo apt-get install make

sudo apt-get install gcc

sudo apt-get install tcl

sudo apt-get install build-essential

sudo apt-get update

## if there is another error like "fatal error: jemalloc/jemalloc.h: No such file or directory"

## just run "make distclean"

make

make test

Comment: Great stuff, thanks. One thing: you are doing `cd redis-stable` twice :)

Comment: Also, if this were to be a shell script, you should use `#` for comments.

Comment: These steps solved my issues installing on Debian.+1

Comment: Every time I install redis, I have to come to this answer :p

Comment: Helped me too, on Centos 7.3.  Thanks!

Comment: Works fine in Ubuntu, even within Windows 10. Seems missing `make install`

Comment: somebody add these to redis installation page 
https://redis.io/download

Comment: Great writeup, solved some issues I had on Ubuntu 16.04 on EC2

Comment: Wonderful solution given. Thanks a ton. I was getting "fatal error: stdlib.h: No such file or directory
 #include <stdlib.h>" error while trying to run make command to build redis on my ubuntu 18.04 server. And the "make distclean" solved my issue.

Answer (score 9):

I got myself into similar situation, hope below steps work

**make distclean**

**sudo make**

Comment: This answer made my day :)

Answer (score 6):

I also use CentOS. You can try this:

```
$ wget http://download.redis.io/releases/redis-3.0.5.tar.gz
$ tar xzf redis-3.0.5.tar.gz
$ cd redis-3.0.5
$ make MALLOC=libc  && make install
```

Answer (score 1):

To install the Redis on Ubuntu, go to terminal and type the following commands:

> $sudo apt-get update
>    $sudo apt-get install redis-server

This will install redis on your machine.

To start Redis

> $redis-server

Check if redis is working?

> $redis-cli

This will open a redis prompt, as shown below:

**redis 127.0.0.1:6379>**

In the above prompt 127.0.0.1 is your machine's IP address and 6379 is port on which redis server is running. Now type the PING command as shown below.

> redis 127.0.0.1:6379> ping

PONG

Answer (score 1):

(Ubuntu) I tried it with installing with synaptic package manager in ubuntu. Synaptic can be installed using 
`sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install synaptic`

ans after installation, just search for redis and install redis-server. It will install redis-client as well.

Answer (score 0):

### Steps to Install Redis on Windows 10:

1. Install linux subsystem through typing "windows features" in windows start:

```
check the box of windows subsystem for linux
then restart
```

2. Install ubunto 22.04 LTS app in microsoft store:

```
open ubunto app
```

3. Add repository by typing:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:redislabs/redis
```

4. Update package manager

```
sudo apt-get update
```

5. Upgrade package manager

```
sudo apt-get update
```

6. Install redis

```
sudo apt-get install redis-server
```

###### Congrats redis is installed!

To confirm version:

```
redis-server --version
```

To run redis:

```
redis-server
```

Open other ubunto app and connect to local host

```
redis-cli
```

Congrats now you can write some cli commands!

Answer (score -3):

You can try somthing like this :

```
$ wget http://redis.googlecode.com/files/redis-2.4.2.tar.gz
$ tar xzf redis-2.4.2.tar.gz
$ cd redis-2.4.2
$ make
```

More info : ( http://redis.io/download )

Comment: this is quite useless, because the root of the error is indicated by the error message and you just change the downloaded file.