# Redis Installation fails with "Newer version of jemalloc required" when running make command

Tags: redis, jemalloc

Redis installation on RHEL fails when running make command. Below is the output

```
cd src && make all
make[1]: Entering directory `/root/Downloads/redis-3.2.0/src'
    CC adlist.o
In file included from adlist.c:34:
zmalloc.h:50:31: error: jemalloc/jemalloc.h: No such file or directory
zmalloc.h:55:2: error: #error "Newer version of jemalloc required"
make[1]: *** [adlist.o] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/root/Downloads/redis-3.2.0/src'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Issue with Redis install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8131008/issue-with-redis-install)

Answer (score 120):

running

```
make distclean
```

and then

```
make
```

solved the issue

Comment: Fixed it for me.  I had run make without realizing that I did not yet have gcc installed.  After installing gcc, I ran into this error because of the aborted first attempt.  This fixed it for me.  Thanks!

Comment: for redis 4.0.8 still I get error `gcc: Command not found` or  `cc: Command not found`

Comment: This worked on Ubuntu 17 - also because I ran `make` without `gcc` installed

Comment: I am still getting the same error. I did this too yum install make gcc gcc-c++ kernel-devel

Comment: This did it for me too, on an Ubuntu terminal in a WSL

Answer (score 7):

It happen due to gcc compiler not available in machine. first install gcc:

```
$ sudo apt install gcc
```

then try

```
make
```

sure it'll resolve this issue . I tried on ubuntu 18.04.

Answer (score 4):

Redis creates the **redis-server** and **redis-cli** files only after the Dependenices in the /deps directory: hiredis lua jemalloc linenoise are resolved. 
I had to run the make command in the deps directory more than once to get the depenedencies resolved.

The following are the Steps I followed:

```
cd <redisInstallationPath> (I have it under /opt/mount1/redis-3.0.7)
make distclean
cd deps/
```

Resolve dependecies more than once.

```
make lua hiredis linenoise
make jemalloc
make hiredis
make linenoise
```

Did the same again as there were a few missing files. I think you just need to get the combination correct. Run the make command more than once till you get it right.

```
make hiredis lua jemalloc linenoise
make hiredis
make lua 
make jemalloc 
make linenoise

cd /opt/mount1/redis-3.0.7/
make
```

-> I got some errors here that the file hiredis/libhiredis.a is not found and hence I continued again to resolve dependecies.

```
cd deps
make jemalloc 
make hiredis
```

ll hiredis/libhiredis.a -> yields a file

```
cd /opt/mount1/redis-3.0.7/
make
```

Now I get the following output:

```
cd src && make all
make[1]: Entering directory `/opt/mount1/redis-3.0.7/src'
LINK redis-server
INSTALL redis-sentinel
CC redis-cli.o
LINK redis-cli
CC redis-benchmark.o
LINK redis-benchmark
CC redis-check-dump.o
LINK redis-check-dump
CC redis-check-aof.o
LINK redis-check-aof

Hint: It's a good idea to run 'make test' ;)

make[1]: Leaving directory `/opt/mount1/redis-3.0.7/src'
```

You can go to Redis installation path (in my case: /opt/mount1/redis-3.0.7 directory) to start the Server.

```
src/redis-server
```

And in another terminal run 'redis-cli' to connect to the Redis Server.

```
src/redis-cli
```

Example:

```
127.0.0.1:6379> incr counter
(integer) 1
127.0.0.1:6379> get counter
"1"
127.0.0.1:6379> exit
```

I got a solution to my problem through this article http://michael.otacoo.com/redis/redis-first-steps-fetch-install-and-server-creation/

Answer (score 3):

Ditch the OS based installation, tried multiple solutions some dependency was always failing

**Node** to the rescue

There are other ways to install Node and NPM below steps is using **Yum** on **Centos / RHEL**

```
# Add NodeSource yum repository
curl -sL https://rpm.nodesource.com/setup_16.x | sudo bash -

# Additional dependencies if required
yum install gcc-c++ make -y

# Install Node.js and npm 
yum install nodejs -y

# install redis-cli
npm install -g redis-cli

# connect to redis endpoint
rdcli -h redis.host
 # or
rdcli -h redis.host -a redis.password -p 1111
```

once connected run

```
PING
```

response should be

> PONG

to validate the connectivity

```
cache.amazonaws.com:6379> PING
PONG
```

Answer (score 1):

**In linux**

May be some of the files required are missing which can be installed with **libc6-dev** package.

This worked for me:-

Go to your redis directory and run the following in your terminal:-

```
sudo apt-get install libc6-dev
make distclean && make
```

Answer (score 0):

That shouldn't be happening. One possible reason could be that your make tools are way older than current version. To update them run:

`yum install make gcc gcc-c++ kernel-devel`

This will install minimum packages, but if even that doesn't solves the problem, try installing the complete group:

`yum install make gcc gcc-c++ kernel-devel`

Read More: https://superuser.com/questions/151557/what-are-build-essential-build-dep

Answer (score 0):

I guess the version 3.2.0 lost some files because I have met the same problem as you, I solved it by downloading another redis version 3.0.7, the download link is

http://download.redis.io/releases/redis-3.0.7.tar.gz

Then, decompress the file and run the command as you have done before, just step into the redis directory and type the command 'make'

Good luck with you

Answer (score 0):

This error may indicate that you need to run make with sudo: `sudo make`

You may afterwards run into:

```
../deps/jemalloc/lib/libjemalloc.a(nstime.o): In function nstime_get':     /opt/redis_src/current/redis-stable/deps/jemalloc/src/nstime.c:120:     undefined reference toclock_gettime'
```

If so, please see:
https://github.com/antirez/redis/issues/3790

Answer (score 0):

**on centos**

```
yum install gcc glibc
tar zxvf redis-5.0.3.tar.gz
cd redis-5.0.3
cd deps
make hiredis jemalloc linenoise lua geohash-int
cd ..
make install
cd utils
./install_server.sh
```

**extra tips**

```
To fix this issue add 'vm.overcommit_memory = 1' to /etc/sysctl.conf and then reboot or run the command 'sysctl vm.overcommit_memory=1' for this to take effect.
    The TCP backlog setting of 511 cannot be enforced because /proc/sys/net/core/somaxconn is set to the lower value of 128
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use Ubuntu PPA

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:redislabs/redis
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install redis
```

Comment: This sounds like an opinion and a "your question itself is wrong" — can you elaborate on why Ubuntu PPA should be used and why it is a solution to the problem as presented?