# Error jemalloc/jemalloc.h: No such file or directory when making Redis

Tags: gcc, redis, jemalloc

I'm try to setup my Redis server, when execute make command, got error: "jemalloc/jemalloc.h: No such file or directory when making Redis", I have tried all steps I can find, such as make distclean or make MALLOC=libc. 
I'm working on CentOS, it is working on my another Ubuntu server.

System information:
Linux ec4t02229 3.10.0-514.10.2.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Mar 3 00:04:05 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Below is my output, any suggestion would be appreciated.

```
[root@ec4t02229 redis-4.0.2]# make
cd src && make all
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/fenxiaop/redis-4.0.2/src'
CC Makefile.dep
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/fenxiaop/redis-4.0.2/src'
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/fenxiaop/redis-4.0.2/src'
rm -rf redis-server redis-sentinel redis-cli redis-benchmark redis-check-rdb redis-check-aof *.o *.gcda *.gcno *.gcov     redis.info lcov-html Makefile.dep dict-benchmark
(cd ../deps && make distclean)
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/fenxiaop/redis-4.0.2/deps'
(cd hiredis && make clean) > /dev/null || true
(cd linenoise && make clean) > /dev/null || true
(cd lua && make clean) > /dev/null || true
(cd jemalloc && [ -f Makefile ] && make distclean) > /dev/null || true
(rm -f .make-*)
    make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/fenxiaop/redis-4.0.2/deps'
(rm -f .make-*)
echo STD=-std=c99 -pedantic -DREDIS_STATIC='' >> .make-settings
echo WARN=-Wall -W -Wno-missing-field-initializers >> .make-settings
echo OPT=-O2 >> .make-settings
echo MALLOC=jemalloc >> .make-settings
echo CFLAGS= >> .make-settings
echo LDFLAGS= >> .make-settings
echo REDIS_CFLAGS= >> .make-settings
echo REDIS_LDFLAGS= >> .make-settings
echo PREV_FINAL_CFLAGS=-std=c99 -pedantic -DREDIS_STATIC='' -Wall -W -Wno-missing-field-initializers -O2 -g -ggdb   -    I../deps/hiredis -I../deps/linenoise -I../deps/lua/src -DUSE_JEMALLOC -I../deps/jemalloc/include >> .make-settings
echo PREV_FINAL_LDFLAGS=  -g -ggdb -rdynamic >> .make-settings
(cd ../deps && make hiredis linenoise lua jemalloc)
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/fenxiaop/redis-4.0.2/deps'
(cd hiredis && make clean) > /dev/null || true
(cd linenoise && make clean) > /dev/null || true
(cd lua && make clean) > /dev/null || true
(cd jemalloc && [ -f Makefile ] && make distclean) > /dev/null || true
(rm -f .make-*)
(echo "" > .make-cflags)
(echo "" > .make-ldflags)
MAKE hiredis
cd hiredis && make static
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/fenxiaop/redis-4.0.2/deps/hiredis'
cc -std=c99 -pedantic -c -O3 -fPIC  -Wall -W -Wstrict-prototypes -Wwrite-strings -g -ggdb x86_64 net.c
cc: error: x86_64: No such file or directory
make[3]: *** [net.o] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/fenxiaop/redis-4.0.2/deps/hiredis'
make[2]: *** [hiredis] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/fenxiaop/redis-4.0.2/deps'
make[1]: [persist-settings] Error 2 (ignored)
CC adlist.o
In file included from adlist.c:34:0:
zmalloc.h:50:31: fatal error: jemalloc/jemalloc.h: No such file or directory    
 #include <jemalloc/jemalloc.h>
                           ^
compilation terminated.
make[1]: *** [adlist.o] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/fenxiaop/redis-4.0.2/src'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: When I tried to run make MALLOC=libc, got error blow
    cc: error: ../deps/hiredis/libhiredis.a: No such file or directory
    cc: error: ../deps/lua/src/liblua.a: No such file or directory
    make[1]: *** [redis-server] Error 1
    make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/fenxiaop/redis-4.0.2/src'
    make: *** [all] Error 2

Comment: Try this whole sequence: make distclean; make MALLOC=libc; make

Comment: This worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37103054/redis-installation-fails-when-running-make-command

Comment: I tried that, didn't work for me. Now I changed my server to Ubuntu from CentOs and installed redis via apt-get install which works well

Comment: Need to run "make distclean" first, it set remove all earlier compilation file and then run "make" so here we get new compilation for redis server program.

Answer (score 56):

same error I was also in while doing build over redis-6.2.0 .

By executing `make distclean` I was out from the error

```
[manjunath@beta-test redis-6.2.0]$ make distclean
```

Comment: Had the same issue, it was because of a first failed `make` command due to not updated packages. The second time I ran `make`, the OP's error occurred. Running `make distclean` then `make` again fixed it.

Comment: thanks, it fixed my problem

Comment: this fixed my problem, too. my first run of make failed because i didn't have gcc.

Answer (score 44):

> Selecting a non-default memory allocator when building Redis is done
> by setting the `MALLOC` environment variable. Redis is compiled and
> linked against libc malloc by default, with the exception of jemalloc
> being the default on Linux systems. This default was picked because
> jemalloc has proven to have fewer fragmentation problems than libc
> malloc.
>
> To force compiling against libc malloc, use:
>
> ```
> % make MALLOC=libc
> ```
>
> To compile against jemalloc on Mac OS X systems, use:
>
> ```
> % make MALLOC=jemalloc
> ```

Source: https://github.com/redis/redis/blob/6.0/README.md#allocator